# What does 「例によって例のごとくや」 mean?

Tags: particles, expressions, dialects, sentence-final-particles, kansai-ben

I have noticed that there is a definition for 「例によって例のごとし」 in a dictionary online but there is slightly difference in the sentence ending, 「くや」 and 「し」. I am not sure if they have the same meaning.

This sentence is said by a manga character who I believe used Kansai dialect because he previously said the following sentence.

> かわいい顔をしとるやないか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this just means, in standard Japanese, 「例によって例のごとくだ」. And it means the same as 「[例によって例のごとし](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/233988/m0u/)だ」. や is a sentence ending particle used in Kansai.

ごとく is the [連用形 of ごとし](http://www.hello-school.net/haroajapa009030.htm) in old Japanese, and thus (例によって)例のごとく is mainly used adverbially. In your example, it's directly followed by だ/や because 例によって例のごとく is treated as a fixed expression.